# wxpython , NameError: global name 'SetTopWindow' is not defined

Tags: python, wxpython

In certain pieces of my app, saying

```
SetTopWindow(self.configFrame)
```

works just fine, but in others, it borks out with:

```
NameError: global name 'SetTopWindow' is not defined
```

code:

```
self.configFrame = configFrame(parent=self, id=-1, title='blabla Configuration')
self.configFrame.Show()
SetTopWindow(self.configFrame)
```

Im sure its something trivial i am missing.  Thanks for All your help!!! :)

V

Comment: Please give some more code to check what's wrong with SetTopWindow

Comment: Certainly, http://pastie.org/2934443, line 100 is the offending line

Answer (score 0):

That's `app.SetTopWindow`, where `app` is your `wx.App`.

Comment: that does not seem to work... also going self.SetTopeWindow produces: NameError: global name 'SetTopWindow' is not defined

Comment: @Clustermagnet: if you get a "global name" error for `self.SetTopWindow`, then you're doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`SetTopWindow` is an wx.App method, as indicated by @larsmans.
You can not use `self.SetTopWindow` for a `wx.Frame` instance because it is not a `wx.Frame` method.
Neither can be used as `SetTopWindow()` as in line 119 in your code because it is not any function you have defined or imported. Thats why you get that "global no defined" exception.